# Not getting right JSON of the when returning list

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Following is the method I am using for returing a list of a model in the form of JSON

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fetchAddress.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody   
public  GenericEntity<List<Address>> fetchAddress(@RequestParam(value="addressId", required=true) int addressId){   
    logger.debug("fetchQueryDetails called");
    List<Address> al =queryDao.fetchAddress(addressId);

    GenericEntity<List<Address>> gal= new GenericEntity<List<Address>>(al){};   
    return gal;      
}
```

}

Following is my model class

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Address")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class AddressImpl implements Address {
     properties, setter, getter.
    }
```

Following is the JSON response I am getting

```
    {"rawType":"java.util.ArrayList","type":{"actualTypeArguments":["com.mvp.Address"],"rawType":"java.util.List","ownerType":null},"entity":[{"flatno":"S-2","houseNo":"42","street":"mother dairy","sector":"sec-2A","city":"kashi","state":"U.P.","country":"India","pin":"200001"},{"flatno":"S-2222222","houseNo":"42","street":"mother dairrrrrrrry","sector":"sec-2AAaa","city":"varansi","state":"U.P.","country":"India","pin":"201101"}]}
```

Now in the JSON reponse I do not want rawType, type, ownerType in the output and also name of entity to be changed something like addressList. Also any idea how can I avoid some of the properties of the bean class not to appear in the JSON. I am using Jackson library for creating JSON. Following are the jars, I am using.

```
     jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar,
     jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar,
     jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar,
     jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
```

Anyone faced the same situation, please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customized names using the annotation @JsonProperty:

```
@JsonProperty("NameOfProperty")
public String getProperty() {
    return property;
}
```

If you don't need a propery, ignore it using : @JsonIgnoreProperties

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public String getPropertyToExclude() {
    return propertyToExclude;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benoit. I was able to ignore the properties I do not want in the JSON. However Along with returning list of objects, I am still getting those raw types and all which I do not want. Also I understand that I can change the name of a property in the JSON output. However how do I name the List. As defualt is coming as entity.

Comment: You can customized how objects are beeing serialized with @JsonValue annotation. Check all supported annotation here http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations